# Laravel Dusk loginAs returns a blank page at http://localhost:8000/_dusk/login/1

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-dusk

Have
trying out basic tests on laravel-dusk, and so far I am unable to automate login using the loginAs function.

```
namespace Tests\Browser;

use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use App\User;

class ModuleTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     * @group plots
     */

    public function loginAsRoot()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->loginAs(User::find(1))
                ->assertSee('some text');
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the chromedriver configured? Is it listening on port 8000 or 9515?

Comment: @AnugerahErlaut I'm having the same problem that MaisondeWamae was having. What do you mean by your questions? What should I be adjusting and where? Thank you! (Apparently he's not active on StackOverflow and didn't respond to your questions, but I am and will.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that the original question-asker [answered his own question here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-dusk-loginas-returns-a-blank-page-at-httplocalhost8000-dusklogin1):

> wamae • Feb 23, 2018 BEST ANSWER Fixed it: Thought the loginAs would
>   hit my default controller "plots" by default, turns out I have to
>   specify it in visit function.

```
use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use App\User;

class PlotsTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     * @group plots
     */

    public function loginAsRoot()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $user = User::find(1);
            $browser->loginAs($user)
                    ->visit('/plots')
                ->assertSee('Deed Plan No');
        });
    }
}
```

(Unfortunately this [doesn't help me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48863394/laravel-dusk-loginas-returns-a-blank-page-at-http-localhost8000-dusk-login-1#comment96209746_48863394) because my test already is using `visit()`.)

Comment: It was me. I was not getting answers on laracasts. So I posted it on stackoverflow

Comment: The quote above the code snippet was helpful - thank you. I had to explicitly call the visit method a second time after a call to loginAs because it didn't automatically redirect me back to the original page I visited, but left me on a blank page.